# TryParse why does it fail if value is zero?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim s as string = "0"
Dim valid as boolean = false
Byte.TryParse(s, valid)
```

Why does `TryParse` fails if the value is zero? It also happens on `Int32.TryParse` etc.

Comment: That wont even compile under `Option Strict`

Comment: Does this even compile ? Been away from VB.NET for a while, but this doesn't compile in c# ! `valid` should be of type `byte` for this to compile in c#.

Comment: @user3185569 I does, if project is not marked with `Option Strict`. VB.NET will happily convert `Byte` to `Boolean` here.

Answer (score 3):

You're parsing out a `Byte` value into `Boolean` variable. VB.NET will let you do that (I'd say unfortunately) and automatically convert `Byte` to `Boolean`. The problem is `Byte` value of `0` is considered `false` when converted to `Boolean` (any non-0 value would be considered `true`). And that's what you're seeing.

What you really want it:

```
Dim s as String = "0"
Dim value as Byte
Dim valid as Boolean = Byte.TryParse(s, value)
```